# Add advanced search options to the help pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, help-center

I was attempting to guide a new user into using the advanced search options today but realised that you can't do it from the Advanced Search Tips link on the search page itself (as it is collapsed by default).  I then tried the [Help Centre page on searching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), however they are not explained here either.

I realise that you can just tell users to go to the search page and click advanced tips, however that seems clunky.  It also seems odd that the extended help page would just send you back to the old page after all the effort that has gone to to set it up.

I know there's a lot to be said for keeping the help pages concise for new users to easily navigate, however I would like to suggest that either **advanced search options are added in full to the search help page** or alternatively **a new help entry for advanced search options is created**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now part of [that same help article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).  [Laura](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166017/laura) took the time to write these up last week and added an advanced search options section.

Starting with the next build, it will also be linked at the bottom of the advanced search tips list.

Answer (score 3):

+1, I agree.  I've been around for a while now, but I haven't always used the advanced search features.  I gradually starting picking them up over time.  I'm amazed to find how helpful they can be / how easy it can be to find what you want when you know how to work the system skillfully.  When I started on SE, I read the FAQ (help page) completely, but I didn't learn anything about the possibilities for advanced searches; I suppose I didn't notice it.  I certainly didn't notice the small orange / blue link off to the side on the search page--it's not very salient.  As a result, it was always quite a chore to try to find something; I would often just use Google to find posts within SE.

The advanced search options should definitely be laid out explicitly on the appropriate help page.