# Look at questions that have a certain tag but not another

Tags: feature-request, tag-search, support

Is there a way to look at questions that have a tag, such as [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), but do not have another tag, such as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?  I know JavaScript, but do not know jQuery, so is there a way for me to look at questions like that?

Comment: Nevermind, just found the answer, in the search just put a minus in front of the tag you don't want. Such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery

Comment: They should advertise this feature, I just tried it because I know google has something just like it.

Comment: It's [already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185456/152859).

Answer (score 10):

This already exists.

Use the `-` search operator, and search [`[javascript] -[jquery]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery).

The operator works for search terms as well as tags.