# Without specifying another search criterion, can I see a list of questions that do not have a particular tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I entered `-[tag-name]` into the search field, intending to have a look at any and all questions on a site that were *not* tagged [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name).

I ended up with no results. The "not this tag" part of the search was successful, but the search engine added the *text* (including quotes) `"-[tag-name]"` to the query.

I can prove it, too! It went like this. I typed my query:

[image]

and got this back:

[image]

Not sure if this is an oversight/bug or as-intended. A [query that includes a negative text term succeeds](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bmagic-the-gathering%5D+-creature), but [multiple negative tags have the same behavior](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bmagic-the-gathering%5D+-%5Bfoo%5D).

Regardless, is there a way to compile such a list? I want to look through all questions on a site that are *not* tagged with a certain tag, without limiting the search any more than that.

Note that this is not the same as "[Look at questions that have a certain tag but not another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185558/look-at-questions-that-do-not-have-a-certain-tag)", because I don't even want to specify another tag that the results *do* have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter that does not restrict the search any further, such as `is:q` (shorthand for `is:question`).

Example: [is:q -[support]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20-%5Bsupport%5D)

---

In other contexts, when the search involves both questions and answers, `views:0` can be used for the same purpose. (It "restricts" to >=0 views).

Comment: Should have thought of that! That does the trick.