# Treat negative-tag searches as if they had is:question

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Example use case: Movies & TV has [a lot of poor questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/why-are-movie-and-tv-show-identification-questions-so-underrated) tagged "identify-this-movie" or "identify-this-tv-show" which clog up the [main questions list](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions) and make it harder to find good content.  So what's the solution?  Do a search for questions that don't contain the tag, using the negation operator for [one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-[identify-this-movie]) or [both](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-[identify-this-movie]%20-[identify-this-tv-show]) of the tags.  Unfortunately, such searches return 0 results, falsely implying that ALL of the questions on that site have one of those tags. It also unexpectedly wraps the query in double quotes.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187736/287315), negative tags are supported "as long as the negative tag isn't the *only* thing in your search."  [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73292/287315) elaborates that tag-negative searches return empty by design:

> For performance reasons, the tag-based NOT operator is disallowed when supplying a single tag. This is because the set of questions without a single tag is a huge set of questions.

I don't quite buy that argument, especially when "[-[identify-this-movie] -[identify-this-tv-show] -identify](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-[identify-this-movie]%20-[identify-this-tv-show]%20-identify)" or even just "[-identify](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-identify)" work as a valid queries, and single-word exclusion seems like it should have poorer performance than tag exclusion.

The [workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242133/287315) is to add something like `is:question` (or the shorter `is:q`, not documented in the Advanced Search Tips) to the query. (It also [works in this example](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-[identify-this-movie]%20-[identify-this-tv-show]%20is%3Aquestion)).  Since answers aren't tagged in the way questions are, it seems likely that someone searching with a negative tag query is likely looking for *questions* that don't have those tags, and returning a result set to match that intention seems more likely to be useful than returning "0 results" (and a query with strangely added quotes) with no indication of what went wrong or what a user can do about it.

Therefore, I make this feature request to **alter the search behavior so that queries which would otherwise return empty because they are negative-tag-only queries, behave as if "is:question" had been appended to the [start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49962/287315) of the query**.

From an implementation perspective, I imagine that somewhere in the query-handling code there is a check to see **if** the query meets certain specifications, **then** *add double quotes, return 0 results, and don't bother telling the user why.*  I'm proposing a change to what happens inside the **then** block.  If for some reason we can't change this behavior to something more useful, we should at the very least explain what's happened.

Comment: Makes sense, although if `is:answer` is explicitly given,  the `is:question` must be removed as when [searching for both](http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bidentify-this-movie%5D+is%3Aanswer+is%3Aquestion), the is:question "wins" so it will cause nobody will be able to search for answers only.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If `is:answer` is explicitly given, **it's not a negative-tag-only query**, so this requested change would not apply.

Comment: oooops, right about that. My bad! :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard no problem, it would have been a helpful potential-secondary-issue to know about if it did apply!