# How to see my own questions?

Tags: support, profile-page

I am very new to Stack Overflow. It's hard for me to find the questions which I asked. How to find out my own questions?

Comment: Click on your display picture on the top center of the screen. Scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your profile by clicking on your profile picture in the top bar.
2. Click on the "*N* Questions" link or go to the "questions" tab.

Answer (score 3):

Click the button inside the top red circle to get to your profile page. Then once you're there, click the "questions" tab (lower red circle). There you'll find your questions!

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: +0. I want to upvote, but...the circles aren't freehand. We gotta do our best to point new users in [the right direction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/246931) you know!

Comment: @NickStauner Ok?

Comment: Beautiful! Perfect! Informative! Authoritative. No one questions a freehand circle.

Comment: @NickStauner Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 1):

You can also search for [`user:me is:question`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: See also Nick Craver's answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185456/246931 for more nifty search tricks like this!